# Missing paramater type for expanded function while mapping

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an exercise to check how many times an element appears in the sequence. I tried to group and then to map the result of values to length, but it says that it missed some arguments. Could you help?
The error: `The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known`

```
def freq[A](seq: Seq[A]): Set[(A, Int)] = {
   seq.groupBy(identity).toSet.map{case (key: A, value: Seq[A]) => (key, value.length: Int)}
  }
  println(freq(Seq(1,2,3,1,3,3,2,1,3,4,5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map before `toSet`:

```
def freq[A](seq: Seq[A]): Set[(A, Int)] = {
  seq.groupBy(identity).map{case (key, value) => (key, value.length)}.toSet
}

println(freq(Seq(1,2,3,1,3,3,2,1,3,4,5)))
```

Comment: thank you... didn't think it could be that easy. Unfortunately I can't give +1, because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @funnyguy a couple of notes if you are in `2.13` you may use `view` to avoid the intermediate collection like `seq.groupBy(identity).view.mapValues(_.length).toSet` you may also use the new `groupMapReduce` like `seq.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _).toSet`

Comment: @Luis what do you mean by "intermediate collection"?

Comment: @funnyguy the `map` after the `groupBy` will create a new **Map** that then will be converted to a **Set**, so those are two operations and will create an intermediate collection that will be garbage-collected after that. `view` is lazy which means the operation is not executed until needed by the `toSet` effectively fusing the two operations in one. - In general, you should not worry about such micro-optimizations unless benchmarking says opposite; but, being the use of `views` that simple and that it also give us the nice `mapValues` then it is great.